# What is the lifetime of a selector?

Tags: objective-c, selector, objective-c-runtime

In Objective-C, there are at least two ways to get (or create? Hence the question) a selector: `@selector(foo:bar:)`, or `NSSelectorFromString(@"foo:bar:")`. But what is the lifetime of a selector?

Since selectors know (at least) their name, they are unlikely to be copiable values of a fixed size that can be shuffled around the program. This means that someone needs to allocate and possibly deallocate them. Most objects from the Cocoa framework have retain-release semantics, which make their ownership explicit and relatively easy to track. However, I see no clear concept of ownership for selectors.

I expect that selectors obtained with the first syntax live as globals for the whole life of the program (like literal strings), but what about the other? If I create/get a selector with `NSSelectorFromString(@"foo:bar:")`, will it be valid for the whole life of my program too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's "get", not "create". Both of those simply *retrieve* the selector, which is created and owned by the runtime system. The `SEL`'s lifetime is therefore effectively immortal.

If you wanted to create a selector yourself, you would need to use the runtime function [`sel_registerName()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-BCIGFJBB). This function is used by `NSSelectorFromString()` if you pass it a name which is as yet unknown to the runtime.

Comment: Incorrect.  `NSSelectorFromString` is documented to call `sel_registerName`.

Comment: Your answer says “Both of those simply *retrieve* the selector”.  That's incorrect.  One of them is documented to create the selector if necessary.

Comment: @robmayoff, I see the ambiguity, but I don't think it's _incorrect_. I think that Josh used "retrieve" (as opposed to "create") to mean that neither gives ownership of the selector to the calling code, regardless of if it existed before.

Comment: @rob: Thanks for the offer, but I'm not interested in getting into a hairsplitting pissing match right now.

Answer (score 4):

As per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString), selectors are registered globally and live forever.  If you pass a new or unknown selector name to `NSSelectorFromString` it will be registered as a new selector.